# Ionic V1 : Error 404 when saving push notification tokens

Tags: android, cordova, curl, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am banging my head angainst the wall because I cannot find why my push notifications do not work.

A small version list :

```
$ cordova plugin info
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.4 "PushPlugin"

$ ionic info
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v5.12.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Here is the code that registers for the push system :

```
// In config
$ionicCloudProvider.init({
 core: {
  app_id: "xxxx"
 },
 push: {
  sender_id: "yyyyyy",
  pluginConfig: {
   ios: {
    badge: true,
   },
   android: {
    iconColor: "#343434"
   }
  }
 }
});

// In controller
// Register Push notifications
$ionicPush.register().then(function (t) {
 console.log('register successfull', t);
 return $ionicPush.saveToken(t, {
  ignore_user: true
 });
}).then(function (t) {
 console.log('Token saved:', t);
 alert('Token saved:', t.token);
});
```

I am debugging with USB android phone, with :

```
ionic run android
```

Then I inspect with chrome device inspector to see what's happening.
Thing is, the 'register successfull' appears, with a "correct" token

```
{
"token": "fWjLt4mOttw:APA91bE4KCycHlu92T6fJTzMFbRFtJdTUrb2u9jv5LTO2yTPD_-sKshbqo93UStwjdJpmLun2tJBCgegaUYnlj9kxxFWFPi9hobZH5W80OnrsPdfxrdYNmp8SYM_SXp-5RiknFrbPl5l",
"app_id": "XXXXXX"
}
```

But the saveToken method fails with a 404 error. When I replay the request with curl in my shell (right-click>Copy>as curl), I have no errors... Here is the chrome console log :

```
POST https://api.ionic.io/push/tokens 404 (Not Found)
Ionic Push: Error: Not Found
at q.<anonymous> (app.js:formatted:717)
at q.t.emit (app.js:formatted:9164)
at XMLHttpRequest.n.onreadystatechange (app.js:formatted:9424)
```

Here is the output from curl (seems correct)

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": 201,
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "request_id": "92487e15-9f2a-416f-c15b-9129e9e10049"
  },
  "data": {
    "token": "fWjLt4mOttw:APA91bE4KCycHlu92T6fJTzMFbRFtJdTUrb2u9jv5LTO2yTPD_-sKshbqo93UStwjdJpmLun2tJBCgegaUYnlj9kxxFWFPi9hobZH5W80OnrsPdfxrdYNmp8SYM_SXp-5RiknFrbPl5l",
    "type": "android",
    "invalidated": null,
    "valid": true,
    "created": "2017-03-07T16:43:58.993190+00:00",
    "app_id": "f2de99a1",
    "id": "c85e1bdbb6b3cf2da8f090ba59df6892"
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue : I had to modify the

```
<allow origin>
```

of the config.xml section.
The 404 error was in fact a 403, but reported as 404 by the browser.